# Idiom - insistent, obtrusive person?

Tags: idiom-request

I am looking for idiom/phrase/proverb showing a moderate disdain for somebody insistent, obtrusive.

There are idioms in other languages like (literally)

*You mean that business traveler? Very annoying guy. **You show him the door, he comes back through the window.***

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are any number of roundabout ways of describing such a person (your own literal translation wouldn't sound unusual coming from a native Anglophone, for example). But in *conventional, standard* English, *He's a **pest*** is extremely common.So common that the "persistent" connotations of the 4-letter noun form have become somewhat watered down (the focus being on the *level* of annoyance, rather than its relentlessness). Thus people sometimes resort to ***pesterer***, but more often that nuance is reclaimed/emphasised using something like *He's always **pestering** me*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a saying:

> He keeps turning up, like a **bad penny**.